# Make a common function to store the local storage data

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am a newbie in react-native. I have a folder structure like below:

```
-screens
  -page1.js
  -page2.js
  -page3.js
  -page4.js
-App.js
```

In page1.js, I have a function to store data to localStorage

```
let obj = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'test@email.com',
    city: 'Singapore'
}
AsyncStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Now I have to display these data in few of my other pages. This is my code.

```
class Page2 extends Component {
    state = {
        username: false
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        const usernameGet = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user');
        let parsed = JSON.parse(usernameGet);
        if (parsed) {
            this.setState({
                username: parsed.name,
                email: parsed.email
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                username: false,
                email: false
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.saved}>
                    {this.state.username}
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default Page2;
```

This is how I display data in page2. I may need to show these in other page too. 
I dont want to repeat these codes in each page.

Any suggestions how to do it in react-native?

Answer (score 1):

**Simplified** Reusable approach of localStorage

```js
export const localData = {
    add(key, value) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    },
    remove(key, value) {
        localStorage.removeItem(key);
    },
    load(key) {
        const stored = localStorage.getItem(key);
        return stored == null ? undefined : JSON.parse(stored);
    },
};

localData.add("user_name", "serialCoder")

console.log( "After set ", localData.load("user_name") )

localData.remove("user_name")

console.log( "After remove ", localData.load("user_name") )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the data you need to display into it's own component and re-use it in any page that you need to display it in.

Another option is to use a [higher-order component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), that way you can wrap it around any components that need the data and it'll be passed down as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `Constant.js` where you can put all your common required utils and constants, reusable anywhere n your app.

In your `Constant.js`:

```
export const USER_DATA = {

 set: ({ user}) => {
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(obj));
   },
   remove: () => {
      localStorage.removeItem('user');
      localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token');
 },
   get: () => ({
     user: localStorage.getItem('user'),
  }),

 }
```

in your any component, you can import it and use like this :

```
import { USER_DATA } from './Constants';


let user = {
name: 'John Doe',
email: 'test@email.com',
city: 'Singapore'
 }

// set LocalStorage

USER_DATA.set(user);

// get LocalStorage

USER_DATA.get().user
```

That's you can make `Constant` common file and reuse them anywhere to avoid writing redundant code.